# Suppose that $\cdot$ is associative and has an identity element. Show that an element $g \in G$ has at most one inverse

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, binary-operations

Let $(G,\cdot)$ be a group with $e$ its neutral element.
For an element $g\in G$, there exists one inverse element in $G$, denoted by $g^{−1}$, such that $g\cdot g^{−1}=g^{−1}\cdot g=e$.

Can this be done any better?

And how can one show that $H:= H_1 \cap H_2$ is a subgroup of $G$, where $H_1$ and $H_2$ are subgroups of $G$?

Let $H=H_1\cap H_2$ where $H_1,H_2\leq(G,\cdot)$. Then, let $a,b\in H$
$\Rightarrow a,b\in H_1\wedge a,b\in H_2$
$\Rightarrow a\cdot b^{−1}\in H_1\wedge a\cdot b^{−1}\in H_2$
$\Rightarrow a\cdot b^{−1}\in H$
$H\leq G$
since $H\subseteq H_1$ and $H\subseteq H_2$.
Proof right?
Thanks

Comment: If $g$ has inverses $a$ and $b$, think about $agb$. For the second question, all you have to do is check that the definition of subgroup is satisfied by that intersection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Let $x', x''\in G$ be two inverses of $x\in G$.
  We have the following:
  $$x'=ex'=(x''x)x'=x''(xx')=x''e=x''.$$

The first equality is because $e$ is neutral element.

Second equality is because $x''$ is inverse of $x$.

Third equality is because of associativity.

The fourth equality is because $x'$ is inverse of $x$.

The fifth equality is because $e$ is neutral element.

- The following characterization of subgroups holds:

  > > Let $(G,\cdot)$ be a group with neutral element $e$ and $H\subseteq G,\ H\neq\emptyset$. $H\leq G$ if and only if $\forall x,y \in H,\ xy^{-1}\in H$.

The "only if" part is clear. For the "if" part:

Since $H\neq \emptyset \Rightarrow\exists a_0\in H$.

From the hypothesis, we get that $a_0a_0^{-1}=e\in H$.

Furthermore, $\forall a\in H$, using the hypothesis, we get that $ea^{-1}=a^{-1}\in H$.

Applying again the hypothesis and the previous result, we get that $\forall a,b \in H: a(b^{-1})^{-1}=ab\in H$. Therefore, $\cdot|_{H\times H}:H\times H \rightarrow H$.

Associativity is inherited from $G$.

$H\neq\emptyset\Rightarrow\exists x\in H\Rightarrow x^{-1}\in H\Rightarrow xx^{-1}\in H\Rightarrow e\in H$.

Using this, we get that if $x,y\in H\Rightarrow x,y\in H_1\wedge x,y\in H_2\Rightarrow xy^{-1}\in H_1 \wedge xy_{-1}\in H_2\Rightarrow xy^{-1}\in H\Rightarrow H\leq G$.

- $G=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{-1\}$ 
  $x \cdot y = x + y + xy$. 
  Let us check that this is an operation on $G$, that means that if $x,y\in G$, then $x\cdot y\in G$. In our case, we would have to show that if $x,y\neq -1\Rightarrow x\cdot y\neq -1$. What does it mean that $x\cdot y =-1$?
  $x+y+xy=-1\Rightarrow x+y+xy+1=0\Rightarrow (x+1)(y+1)=0$. Therefore if $x, y\neq -1$, $x\cdot y\neq -1$., which makes $\cdot $ an operation on $G$.

Now to check associativity, i.e. if $x,y,z\in G$, then $(x\cdot y)\cdot z=x\cdot (y\cdot z) $
$(x\cdot y)\cdot z= (x\cdot y) +z +(x\cdot y)z=x+y+xy+z+(x+y+xy)z=x+y+z+xy+xz+yz+xyz=x+(y+z+yz)+x(y+z+yz)=x+y\cdot z +x(y\cdot z)=x\cdot (y\cdot z)$.

$0$ is the neutral element. Indeed if $x\in G$: $x\cdot 0=x+0+x0=x=0\cdot x$.

To check for the inverse element: $x\cdot x^{-1}=0\Rightarrow x+x^{-1}+xx^{-1}=0\Rightarrow x^{-1}{1+x}=-x\Rightarrow x^{-1}=\frac{-x}{1+x}$.

I think you can compute your answer. Hope it is helpful.

Comment: Thanks, This was very precise and helped me a lot. Do you think you can help me with this question: let G:= {g ∈ ℝ : g cannot be -1} and let g1 * g2 = g1 + g2 + g1g2. Is (G,*) a group and please justify and if so what would the inverse be if element g = 5?  * is an operation on G. Thank you!

Comment: @kane You need to check associativity, which isn't too hard; just show that $(a*b)*c=a*(b*c)$. To find the identity, solve $a*e=a$ for $e$ (that is, solve $a+e+ae=a$ for $e$). Once you have that, to find the inverse of $5$, solve $5*x=e$.

Comment: @columbus8myhw So would this be right for associativity? (g1 + g2 ) + g1g2 = g1 + (g2 + g1g2) therefore is a group ? and would the inverse of 5 be -5/6. Thanks

Comment: @kane No for your associativity proof. You need to deal with _three_ variables. What is $(g_1*g_2)*g_3$? Write it out. What is $g_1*(g_2*g_3)$? The inverse seems fine to me.

Comment: @columbus8myhw I see, and if both of the values equal to each other then it's associative therefore is a group? I would like to show my working however it is very long winded to type.

Comment: @kane I posted an answer.

Comment: @lulia brilliant thanks a lot! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

a,b belongs to H,subset of G if ab^(-1) belongs to H then H is subgroup of G
H1 meet H2 is nonempty as 1 belongs to both of it
let a,b belongs to H1 meet H2 then ab^(-1) belongs to H1 and H2 { as H1 ,H2 are subgroups}
ab^(-1) belongs to H
hence h is subgroup

Comment: Thanks! can you check the first part please

Comment: let a have 2 inverses b , c then ab=ba=1 and ac=ca=1 consider                 bac = (ba)c=1c=c again bac=b(ac)=b1=b hence b=c hence the proof

Comment: Thanks! Do you think you can help me with this question: let G:= {g ∈ ℝ : g cannot be -1} and let g1 * g2 = g1 + g2 + g1g2.  Is (G,*) a group and please justify and if so what would the inverse if element g = 5? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry I accidentally forgot to put question in. Please check again

Comment: yes it is. closure property holds if not then g1*g2=(-1) implies g1=[-(1+g2)/(1+g2)]= -1,a contradiction as g1,g2 belongs to G so g1,g2 are not equal to (-1) so g1*g2 belongs to G then check the associative law it holds . Let e be the identity element g*e=g implies e=0 then let g' be the inverse of g  so g'= -(g/(1+g)) now g is not equal to 1+g so g' is not equal to -1 so g' belongs to G  then inverse of 5= -(5/6)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's very helpful